# Compare day in current month to same day previous month PostgreSQL

Tags: date, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to compare values of current month's data to previous months using PostgreSQL. So if today is 4/23/2018, I want the data for 3/23/2018.

I've tried `current_date - interval '1 month'` but it is problematic for months with 31 days.

My table is structured as simply as

> date, value

Comment: What do you expect to be the previous month date for 31th then?

Comment: It'll just be null for the 31st day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this example query:

```
WITH dates AS (SELECT date::date FROM generate_series('2018-01-01'::date, '2018-12-31'::date, INTERVAL '1 day') AS date)
SELECT
    start_dates.date AS start_date,
    end_dates.date AS end_date
FROM
    dates AS start_dates
    RIGHT JOIN dates AS end_dates
    ON (    start_dates.date + interval '1 month' = end_dates.date AND
            end_dates.date - interval '1 month' = start_dates.date);
```

It will output all `end_dates` and corresponding `start_dates`. The corresponding dates are defined by `interval '1 month'` and checked in both ways:

```
start_dates.date + interval '1 month' = end_dates.date AND
end_dates.date - interval '1 month' =  start_dates.date
```

The output looks like this:

```
....
2018-02-26  2018-03-26
2018-02-27  2018-03-27
2018-02-28  2018-03-28
            2018-03-29
            2018-03-30
            2018-03-31
2018-03-01  2018-04-01
2018-03-02  2018-04-02
2018-03-03  2018-04-03
2018-03-04  2018-04-04
....
```

Note, that there are 'gaps' for days without corresponding dates.

---

Back to your table, join the table with itself (giving aliases) and use given join condition, so the query would look like this:

```
SELECT
    start_dates.value - end_dates.value AS change,
    start_dates.date AS start_date,
    end_dates.date AS end_date
FROM
    _your_table_name_ AS start_dates
    RIGHT JOIN _your_table_name_ AS end_dates
    ON (    start_dates.date + interval '1 month' = end_dates.date AND
            end_dates.date - interval '1 month' = start_dates.date);
```

Comment: Thanks! I should have mentioned I am using Redshift so generate_series does not work.I tried an alternative:
 `WITH dates AS (select (current_date::date - generate_series)::date as date from generate_series(1,1000,1)) 
SELECT
    start_dates.date AS start_date,
    end_dates.date AS end_date
FROM
    dates AS start_dates
    RIGHT JOIN dates AS end_dates
    ON (    
            start_dates.date + interval '1 month' = end_dates.date 
            AND end_dates.date - interval '1 month' =  start_dates.date
      )` 
but this can't be joined to any other tables given Redshift's limits

Comment: That was only an example. Remove `WITH` clause and replace `dates` with your real table name (_table_name_ AS start_dates RIGHT JOIN _table_name_ AS end_dates). In general: join the table with itself (giving aliases) and use given join condition.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following table structure:

```sql
create table t (
  d date, 
  v int
 );
```

After populating with some dates and values, there is a way to find the value of the previous month using simple calculations and the [LAG](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/functions-window.html) function, without resorting to joins. I am not sure how it compares from a performance perspective, so please run your own tests before selecting which solution to use.

```sql
select
    *,
    lag(v, day_of_month) over (order by d) as v_end_of_last_month,
    lag(v, last_day_of_previous_month + day_of_month - cast(extract(day from d - interval '1 month') as int)) over (order by d) as v_same_day_last_month 
from (
    select 
        *,
        lag(day_of_month, day_of_month) over (order by d) as last_day_of_previous_month
    from (
        select 
            *,
            cast(extract(day from d) as int) as day_of_month
        from 
            t
    ) t_dom
 ) t_dom_ldopm;
```

You may note that between the 29th and 31st of March, the comparison will be made against the 28th of February, since the same day does not exist in February for those particular dates. The same logic applies to other months with different number of days.